# Minimum JDK for Groovy

Tags: java, groovy

I'm looking to write some Groovy code to perform tasks inside of install anywhere but because of the platforms we support I'm restricted to java 1.5.  Any idea if this will be sufficient to run the latest groovy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java 1.5 should work. The Groovy docs state that you [need at least 1.4](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Tutorial+1+-+Getting+started). I use Groovy with Java 1.5, and everything works fine as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 3):

As of early 2015, the build environment for groovy 2.4.0 (in the build.gradle file) indicates:

```
sourceCompatibility = 1.6
targetCompatibility = 1.6
```

So, for modern groovy, you want 1.6 or better. The documentation for 2.4 indicates JDK 1.5 support, which disagrees with the build environment, so be warned if you're stuck on 1.5.

In addition, there's support for use of the `invokeDynamic` instruction in later releases of JDK 1.7 (it was present but known to be buggy in releases older than JDK 7u60) which may offer some performance improvements.